# get array string from firebase on android

Tags: android, firebase

I have array list on android it's worked . 
in past i was write the array string at the code like :

```
String[] string = {"st1","st2","st1"}
```

I was made connection the app to firebase and i was success to get string .

I  want to get the string array from firebase, but i don't know how!
i was read about that but not helpful for me.

i was put the strings  at the array list as function on Fragment.

so my code is :

```
    private ArrayList<City> initCities() {
    Log.d(TAG, "ArrayList_CitiesFragment_initCities");
    String[] cityName = {"st1","st2","st3"};
    ArrayList<City> theCities = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String aCityName : cityName) {
        City city = new City(aCityName, false);
        theCities.add(city);
    }
    return theCities;
}
```

then at the onViewCreate operation the function.
i want  it from the firebase.

i don't know how..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add **addValueEventListener()** method to receive the events whenever there is change in data.

Here is the sample code as you have not mentioned clearly your database structure and what part you want to retrieve.

```
ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>;
final DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatbase.getInstance().getReferenece().child("Your_Child_Name");
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
for(Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : ((Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue()).entrySet())
               {
                   Map singlet = (Map) entry.getValue();
                   names.add((String)singlet.get("COLUMN_NAME_OF_DATABASE_YOU_WANT"));
               }
 }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "AWW SNAP... Something is Wrong.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: i was copy your sample code , i have an exception : `                  java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Map
` .   it's at line  `                    Map singlet = (Map) entry.getValue();
`